# array to string with edit of each element

Tags: javascript

I have array of strings:

```
var array = ['1', '2', '3'];
```

How to convert array to string to get finally such result:

```
var str = '"1","2","3"';
```

Tried such code:

```
var arr = ['1', '2', '3'];
var arrString = arr.join(",");
```

but receive:

```
var str = '1,2,3'; without "
```

Comment: Good home work question, Try it.

Answer (score 2):

You weren't too far off, now all you need is your double quotes.

```
var arrString = '"' + arr.join('","') + '"';
```

Of course, if there are no array items to join you'll get a string with just `""`, so make a check for that:

```
var arrString = arr.length ? '"' + arr.join('","') + '"' : '';
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bjzrauuw/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var array = ['1', '2', '3'];
var ret = "";

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  ret += "\"" + array[i] + "\",";
}

ret = ret.substr(0, ret.length - 1); // remove last ,

console.log(ret); // output "1","2","3"
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mxwztrsd/)

Answer (score 0):

homework... this stuff isn't hard! anyhoew, since i didn't like the other answers:

```
var array = [1,2,3];
var output = array.map(function(val) {
    return '"' + val + '"';
}).join(',');
```

gives you the correct output, no mather the ammount of elements in the list.